# Data scraping different asset class data

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to write some code that will scrape different asset class data. The user enters the name of a stock that they want to get information on and then the code fetches relevant quantitative data for that particular stock.

I was thinking VBA as it would be easy to have the data output into an excel spreadsheet. But am open to other languages if it is easier (I know a small bit of Python).

The problem I'm having is there don't seem to be any unique tags to look at to then be able to access the tables of data that I would want.

E.g. I could `GetElementsByClassName("clear")` but many of these exist. I thought maybe I can access the table class name itself. I have two issues with this:

1): I can't get it to work in VBA as it doesn't seem to like the spaces that this class name has

2): Even if I get it to work, I don't know if the class name will be the same for over stocks...

Any suggestions really appreciated. This is my most complex VBA project.

[image: Tag example]

Comment: Can't you get the table's `<tbody>` and then iterate its `<td>` children?

Comment: BTW you can get the table with the `companyFinancialSummaryTbl` class (the `class="..."` attribute is a space-delimited *list of CSS classes*; your selector can use any *one* of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I can't get it to work in VBA as it doesn't seem to like the spaces that this class name has*

The element has 3 classes; CSS classes don't have spaces in them.

You could `GetElementsByClassName("companyFinancialSumaryTbl")`, that would get you a collection of nodes that includes the `<table>` element, presumably as the first and only item.

From there you can get the `<tbody>` child element, and then you can iterate its `<tr>` children, and in each row you can iterate the `<td>` child nodes; when a `<td>` has the `bold` class you know you're looking at a row heading.

> *Even if I get it to work, I don't know if the class name will be the same for over stocks...*

We don't know either! If there's another table to read data from, it probably doesn't have the `companyFinancialSummaryTbl` class, likely has some `overstocksTbl` class instead; either way, it'll be a `<table>` element with child nodes that you can navigate and iterate.

I'm not super familiar with web scraping, but say you have the `<table>` element in object `e`, then you could conceivably get the `<tbody>` element like this:

```
Dim thead As Object
Set thead = e(0)

Dim tbody As Object
Set tbody = e(1)
```

If that works, then this should too:

```
Dim tr As Object
For Each tr In tbody
    Dim td As Object
    For Each td In tr
        Debug.Print td,; ' comma prints a tab, semicolon skips printing the line break
    Next
    Debug.Print 'print the line break
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't share a URL, but I'll show you how I would do this, generically.  You can abstract the idea to your specific use case.

```
Sub Web_Table_Option_Two()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set sht = wb.Sheets("Stocks")

    'find last used row in ColumnA
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

    mystock = c.Value

        objIE.Navigate "https://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/" & mystock & "/details"

        Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = mystock

        ActRw = 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) 'wait for java script to load
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
        With HTMLDoc.body
            Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
            For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
                For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                    For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                    Next lngCol
                Next lngRow
                ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
            Next lngTable
        End With

    Next c

    objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]